# Is resonance possible with consecutive double bonds?

Tags: resonance

Resonance is delocalisation of pi electrons among parallel unhybridized p orbitals,  so if we consider a molecules with 4 carbon chain with all bonds between carbon being doubly bonded then not all the unhybridized p orbitals would be parallel to each other ,

So in such a case is it possible for the molecule to have resonance,  like in Butatriene  I think there would be no resonance ? Is it right or am I studying something very very off.

Comment: Questions that consist merely just of questions without a priori elaboration are usually closed on most sites of the StackExchange network.

Comment: You'll find your answer by reading about allene.